# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Crashlytics Gradle plugin version 1.25.4 and higher

Tags: android, react-native

After couple of months of not working on my app I have decided to continue and before doing so I wanted to update all dependencies, libraries etc.

After 3h+ of a nightmare with googles nonsense I am at the final (probably not even close) stage.

This error of:

> The Android Gradle plugin supports only Crashlytics Gradle plugin
>   version 1.25.4 and higher.

Is driving me nuts. I did a global search on my project of `1.25.4` and 1 result came up which was for the `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'` so I changed it to `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'` and hoped for the best.. But the same error keeps coming up every time I am trying to build the app..

**Can anyone tell me what kind of magic potion should I spray this gradle so it actually starts to work?**

Answer (score 0):

add this to the root project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1"
    }
}
```

and this on top of the module level's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "io.fabric"
```

Comment: I have it all added but I added 1.26.1 instead of 1.25.4 but thats the same issue.. Downgrading `com.android.tools.build:gradle` from 3.2.0 to 3.1.1 actually builds

Comment: @AlwaysConfused use `3.2.1` and delete `caches` and `build` directories. possibly Gradle is in offline mode and won't fetch anything new; therefore stuck with old versions. deleting this directories will certainly enforce the project to sync - and also show if it's offline mode, when it fails to fetch.

Comment: That did not help at all.. Have no idea why its giving me this error at all

Comment: @AlwaysConfused your question lacks the `build.gradle` which would be required to provide a concrete answer. the default `build.gradle` does not even feature any version `3.1.1` either. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/build.gradle you might be using an outdated version of react. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve